# in Yii 1.1.project images in uploaded are not shown on remote server

Tags: php, image, yii, upload

I uploaded my  Yii 1.1.14 project on remote server and found that images in upload dir are not shown.

Image in "images" directory like:
`http://remote-server.com/tybapp/assets/mine/images/delete.png`
is shown ok

Image in "uploads/" directory like:
`http://remote-server.com/tybapp/uploads/cms_items/-cms_item-43/5cd790612da5.jpg`
 are not shown and copied to browser it showes error

> Unable to resolve the request
>   "uploads/cms_items/-cms_item-43/44c9cc2b1edd.jpg".

Is it access error or what? On local server it worked ok.
As for access I tried to set access 0755 to all dirs and files or 0755 to all dirs and 0644 to all files - with the same result.

Comment: it is probably related to absolute and relative paths.
`<img src="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/uploads/filename.jpg" />` will point the files to the correct basedir

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that I have to edit my .htaccess for skipping images from yii pages routings ? If yes in which way ?

Comment: Minor issue but didn't think of that You solved it..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check folder permissions and try giving permission to `uploads` folder. Always make sure to give permissions when uploading to server.